# i am getting the following error when writting the CRUDRepository. Error:Discription: The injection point has the following annotations:

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-annotations

[image: Error in Description:]

[image: Starter of application:]

[image: Bean]

package com.example.book.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.book.bean.Book;

@Repository
public interface BookCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer> {

}

Comment: Could you kindly provide your Service class, format your question and provide the error stack as a quote, instead of the image which is not completely visible? also, in the future, prefer code text snippets over images.

Answer (score 0):

*Hey guys i got the solution which i was facing...* **The injection point has following annotations**

### main class

*after adding the following annotations...*

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.model"})
```

### pom.xml

*after configuring the mysql correct version which is installed on your localHost...*

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
```

### application.properties

*after adding this properties...*

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```